# CORS error in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cross-domain, cross-platform, cors

When I am using Fiddler or any browser side HTTP client extension like Advanced Rest Client, I can get data from a API easily. 
But when I try to use the same API from Angular JS, CORS issue appear immediately. I have tried with following lines to solve the problem in AngularJS, But unfortunately it did not work.

```
appd.config(function ($httpProvider) {
  //  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
    // $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Accept'] = '*/*'
    $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
    $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
    delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"];
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["Accept"] = "*/*";
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic encodedpassword=';
});
```

I get following error in mozilla:

Cross-Origin Request Blocked:

```
The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://host/training_webapi. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.
```

And following in Chrome:

```
 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://host/training_webapi The request was redirected to 'http:host/training_webapi/', which is disallowed for cross-origin requests that require preflight.
```

Answer (score 0):

The service you are requesting is not allowing CORS (no Access-Control are sent as part of the response).
You would need to include the header Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * as part of the response (which it does not).

See this : http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer. But it works with Rest-clients. T.E. Fiddler or others

Comment: @Muffin Unlike browsers, user agents like Fiddler, Postman, etc. do not enforce the Same-Origin Policy.

Answer (score -1):

You might be able to use [$http.jsonp](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#jsonp).

```
var url = "http://host/training_webapi?callback=JSON_CALLBACK";

$http.jsonp(url)
    .success(function(data){
        console.log(data.found);
    });
```

Working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/subhaze/a4Rc2/114/)

Another option (since you don't own the server), could be to proxy the request on your server and access that URI using angular.

One more point, in your code the content header is set to form:

```
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
```

Your request should be expecting

```
content-type: application/json
```

Comment: JSONP is a dangerous hack, esp. if credentials are allowed. CORS is the preferred mechanism for cross-origin mechanism, nowadays.